# Antlr4 - How to get left and right sibling of rule context using java

Tags: java, antlr4

I have created a grammar using `antlr`.
now i have to get left and right siblings of rule context using java.

`Antlr` provides capability to get children rule context and parent rule context using `ctx.parent()` and `ctx.children`.

Is there any way to find siblings of any rule context?

Comment: Can you specify more? Show us your grammar, what you need to get and why?

Comment: Also what exactly is sibling to you? (I wanted to write "in this context", but that would just be confusing :)